# How to disable process isolation in Symfony2

Tags: php, unit-testing, symfony, phpunit

I have tested methods using phpunit, almost are done and working fine, but my some of methods are not working and need to disable process isolation, I am finding about how to disable this, but not getting any idea about disable it, please tell me if anyone have to know how to disable process isolation in symfony2?

Thanks

Comment: The whole purpose of unit testing is to run your test subjects in isolated/controlled environments, with known input data to check for wrong output

Comment: Thanks Udan, can you explain some with details so I will go ahead with your solutions

Comment: Why do you think you need not to isolate the process?

Comment: We just know how to disable the isolate?

Comment: because of https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/1171

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for `"processIsolation"` property in your `phpunit.xml.dist` file and set it's value to "false"

The file is usually located in the Symfony project's "app" folder.